# How to use intents to send a user input data from one activity to another

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, android-activity

The code below is the source code for the **third** and **fourth** activity.The third activity receives a user input and performs a mathematical operation on it. Then both the original and processed values are send to the fourth activity where it needs to be displayed. I am not quite familiar with the use of intents. Can somebody check my code? It's not working.

**Third Activity**

```
public class Third extends Activity {

double x=0, val1=0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.third);

    final EditText et;
    final Button b;

    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Third.this, Fourth.class);
            intent.putExtra("thetext", et.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent);

            x=Double.parseDouble(et.getText().toString());

            val1=(x*.04);

            Intent in1 = new Intent(Third.this, Fourth.class);
            in1.putExtra("thevalue1",val1);
            startActivity(in1);

        }


  });

}
}
```

**Fourth Activity:**

```
public class Fourth extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fourth);

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("thetext"));


    TextView wt1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView12);
    wt1.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("thevalue1"));
} 

}
```

Comment: What is your problem? What have you got? Where is error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put both extras into one `Intent` and only call `startActivity(...)` once. Change the code of your Third `Activity` (in the `onClick(...)` method) as follows...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Third.this, Fourth.class);
intent.putExtra("thetext", et.getText().toString());
x=Double.parseDouble(et.getText().toString());
val1=(x*.04);
intent.putExtra("thevalue1",val1);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Got it! How about the Fourth activity? How to extract the two values from the bundle?

Comment: @user3211607 : Just it as you show in the code you posted. It should work.

Comment: It is showing error: The method setText(CharSequence) in the type TextView is not applicable for the arguments (double)

Comment: That's because you're trying to set the text of a `TextView` with a `Double`. Just do the reverse of what you did in Third `Activity` and convert back to a `String` using `String.valueOf(...)`.

Comment: Sir, one more doubt.. Can I send multiple number of values added to the same bundle in the same way as shown above? Is there any limit?

Comment: Yes you can send multiple values and there isn't a limit as long as they all have a unique 'key'.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. @Squonk please do you think you could give me your opinion on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25598696/recommended-way-order-to-read-data-from-a-webservice-parse-that-data-and-inse

Answer (score 1):

You are starting 2 different activities. I think what you want is to set multiple intent extras instead and then start the activity:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Third.this, Fourth.class);

    intent.putExtra("thetext", et.getText().toString());

    x=Double.parseDouble(et.getText().toString());
    val1=(x*.04);
    intent.putExtra("thevalue1",val1);

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

In your example you start 1 activity with only the **text** and another which has only the **double**. Yet in both activities you are trying to get **both** of the values.

Also note that for final variables you need to set them when declaring like this:

```
final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
final Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Answer (score 0):

In fourth activity do this

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("thetext"));


    TextView wt1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView12);
    wt1.setText(getIntent().getDoubleExtra("thevalue1"));
```

The `getExtras()` method is for bundle, you storing in third activity in intent

```
in1.putExtra("thevalue1",val1);
```

Comment: This won't solve anything. The extras of an `Intent` are carried in a `Bundle`. Calling `getStringExtra(...)` and `getDoubleExtra(...)` are simply convenience methods for calling `getExtras().getString(...)` and `getExtras().getDouble(...)`.

Comment: When i try that iam getting an error: The method getDoubleExtra(String, double) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: try this `wt1.setText(String.valueOf(getIntent().getDoubleExtra("thevalue1")));`